# MySQL returning opposite values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, forum

**Thanks anyways guys, it turned out that I just put the wrong data into the database.**

I am having an issue or two. I am currently working on a php forum, and I need to get all records where their `topc_cat` equals 1.. Problem is, it returns the opposite (it only returns the values if it doesn't equal 1).. I'm not sure why this is. Here's my code:

```
public function getFrom($table, $where){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE 'topic_cat' = {$where}"; 
    if ($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {           
        if ($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        }
    }
    return $this->results;
}
```

When `$where` is a value of 1, it returns nothing. If I change it to `WHERE 'topic_cat' != {$where}`, it returns this:

```
stdClass Object ( [topic_id] => 1 [topic_subject] => Test Topic [topic_date] => 2013-12-31 19:42:01 [topic_cat] => 1 [topic_by] => 0 ) stdClass Object ( [topic_id] => 2 [topic_subject] => Test Topic 2 [topic_date] => 2013-12-31 19:42:01 [topic_cat] => 1 [topic_by] => 0 )
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE topic_cat = {$where}";

Comment: can you show the values of $table and $where?

Comment: When you put `'topic_cat' = ` you are actually comparing the STRING "topic_cat" to 1. That is why you're getting results if != and no results if =.  Take out the single quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use quation in column name and you also missed `$` in table variable: try this:

```
public function getFrom($table, $where){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE topic_cat = {$where}"; 
    if ($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {           
        if ($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        }
    }
    return $this->results;
}
```

Comment: That is just what I was thinking, unless of course the single quotes are actually back ticks.

Comment: Just to clarify in case it's not obvious, the reason for this is the string '`topic_cat'` can never equal 1, so that's why you get no rows when using = 1, and you do get rows using != 1. By using `'` instead of ` you made the column name a string.

Answer (score 0):

In this case your issue is you're using the string literal 'topic_cat' which means that you're evaluating cases in which the string 'topic_cat' (not the column topic_cat) is equal to $where. Also are you sure that {table} shouldn't be {$table}?

And stylistically, since you're using prepared statements, why not use named attributes and inject them at prepare time? e.g.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE topic_cat = :topicCatWhere";
if ($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql, array(':topicCatWhere' => $where))) { 
   ...
}
```